# Bitbake: getting dependencies of a recipe, from bbclass using python

Tags: python, dependencies, bitbake

How is it possible to get the dependencies of a recipe, from a bbclass, i.e. using python? I can get the variable DEPENDS, which is fine, but I would need to get the dependencies of any recipe with a certain name.

So I would need a function that is like:
deps = getDependencies(recipeName)

Where deps is the list of recipes, the "recipeName" recipe depends on.